# How to prevent "the application has requested permission to establish connections" popups?

Tags: java

Starting with JRE8U25, our users are getting "the application has requested permission to establish connections to" errors with the IP address of any one of our DNS servers following it.  I've seen other posts on the topic of this error, but non of them seem to apply (this is new with 8U25 so it's not the old 7U5 bug, nor is it going back to localhost).

There's just one piece of code that references DNS servers, and that's to find out which MX to use for sending mail.  So, I know exactly where it's coming from, but I have no idea why it's worked fine for years only to fail now.

If it matters, this is a JWS/JNLP launched application.  The problem is also quite intermittent.  I've never seen it on my dev box, but some users see it multiple times a day (but not even every time the code is called to do the lookup).

Happens in this block:

```
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();
    env.put("java.naming.factory.initial","com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory");
    DirContext ictx = new InitialDirContext( env );
    Attributes attrs = ictx.getAttributes("domain.com", new String[] { "MX" });
    Attribute attr = attrs.get( "MX" );
    NamingEnumeration en = attr.getAll();
```

Has there been a JNLP launch security change that I need to make?

Comment: show some code and ask a question

Comment: Perhaps it's your firewall that blocks?

Comment: It's not the firewall.  Hitting OK on the JRE warning message allows it to finish processing most of the time.  I have had a couple reports that the JRE (and all applications using it) will sometimes lock up when that message box pops up.

Comment: I get a similar issue with U45 but not with U31.

Comment: Found an earlier question that this is a duplicate of.  Please help me close this one properly!  :-)